# when i click the anchor tag to hide the tooltip, it still shows it

Tags: jquery

I have a tooltip that I have created which when I click shows the tooltip however, when  click close, the inline style still shows as `block` instead of `none`.

```js
$(".question-circle").hover(function(){
    //$(".popup-background").show();
    $(".tooltip-text").show();
});

$(".close-tooltip").click(function(){
    //$(".popup-background").fadeOut(); 
    $(".tooltip-text").hide();
                        
});
```

```css
.question-circle {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 4px;
}

.tooltip-text {
    top: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background: #fff;
    color: #5e5e62;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 230px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: none;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    border: solid 1px #C4C4C4;
    z-index: 9999;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 13px #848484;
    line-height: 17px;
}

.tooltip-text a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.tooltip-text::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    top: -24%;
    border: 15px solid;
    border-color: #fff #12000000 #0000 #0000;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}.question-circle {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 4px;
}

.tooltip-text {
    top: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background: #fff;
    color: #5e5e62;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 230px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: none;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    border: solid 1px #C4C4C4;
    z-index: 9999;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 13px #848484;
    line-height: 17px;
}

.tooltip-text a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.tooltip-text::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    top: -24%;
    border: 15px solid;
    border-color: #fff #12000000 #0000 #0000;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

````html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```
<div class="question-circle">
    <img src="https://dev.touchneurology.com/wp-content/themes/tmm/images/graphics/circle-question-regular.svg">
    <span class="tooltip-text show-tooltip kjk">Words here to explain what touchINCONVERSATION is. Nothing too wordy but enough to give user an idea of what it is about.
        <a class="close-tooltip" href="#">Close</a>
     </span>
</div>
````

Comment: Created a fiddle for you, its just works, but the svg you are using comes from a protected site. https://jsfiddle.net/ho5b28cu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the other answer, you are still hovering over the container while clicking to close the tooltip. As solution is to remove the event handler and reapply the event handler after you've hidden the tooltip

```js
$(".question-circle").on('mouseover', function(){
    showTooltip($(this));
});



function showTooltip(parent) {
    parent.off('mouseover');

    $(".tooltip-text", parent).show();

    $(".close-tooltip", parent).on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().hide(300, function() {      
            parent.on('mouseover', function() {
                showTooltip($(this));
            });
        });
    });
}
```

```css
.question-circle {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 4px;
}

.tooltip-text {
    top: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background: #fff;
    color: #5e5e62;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 230px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: none;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    border: solid 1px #C4C4C4;
    z-index: 9999;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 13px #848484;
    line-height: 17px;
}

.tooltip-text a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.tooltip-text::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    top: -24%;
    border: 15px solid;
    border-color: #fff #12000000 #0000 #0000;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}.question-circle {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 4px;
}

.tooltip-text {
    top: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background: #fff;
    color: #5e5e62;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 230px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: none;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    border: solid 1px #C4C4C4;
    z-index: 9999;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 13px #848484;
    line-height: 17px;
}

.tooltip-text a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.tooltip-text::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    top: -24%;
    border: 15px solid;
    border-color: #fff #12000000 #0000 #0000;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question-circle">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/1000/1000.jpg?hmac=5nME13-xBzl4yi2t1tFev6zsf5IWO2-efZAoXEm9ltc">
    <span class="tooltip-text show-tooltip kjk">Words here to explain what touchINCONVERSATION is. Nothing too wordy but enough to give user an idea of what it is about.
        <a class="close-tooltip" href="#">Close</a>
     </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are still hovering `.question-circle` the `.show()` kicks back in again.

I have added the class to the image instead of the div.

```js
$(".question-circle").hover(function(){
    //$(".popup-background").show();
    $(".tooltip-text").show();
});

$(".close-tooltip").click(function(){
    //$(".popup-background").fadeOut(); 
    $(".tooltip-text").hide();
                        
});
```

```css
.question-circle {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 4px;
}

.tooltip-text {
    top: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background: #fff;
    color: #5e5e62;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 230px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: none;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    border: solid 1px #C4C4C4;
    z-index: 9999;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 13px #848484;
    line-height: 17px;
}

.tooltip-text a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.tooltip-text::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    top: -24%;
    border: 15px solid;
    border-color: #fff #12000000 #0000 #0000;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}.question-circle {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 4px;
}

.tooltip-text {
    top: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background: #fff;
    color: #5e5e62;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 230px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: none;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    border: solid 1px #C4C4C4;
    z-index: 9999;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 13px #848484;
    line-height: 17px;
}

.tooltip-text a {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.tooltip-text::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    top: -24%;
    border: 15px solid;
    border-color: #fff #12000000 #0000 #0000;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <img  class="question-circle" src="https://dev.touchneurology.com/wp-content/themes/tmm/images/graphics/circle-question-regular.svg">
    <span class="tooltip-text show-tooltip kjk">Words here to explain what touchINCONVERSATION is. Nothing too wordy but enough to give user an idea of what it is about.
        <a class="close-tooltip" href="#">Close</a>
     </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Just moving the tooltip is not a real solution though

Comment: @DarkBee answer has just moved the class so the div is no longer styled which is why the tooltip has moved

Comment: That is just moving the problem. Add any image that actually fills the container and you are at square 1 - [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sextw324/)

Comment: @DarkBee I don't think a question-circle will be a full page image. I just pointed out the problem and gave a quick fix. Now topic starter knows the origine from the bug and can see how the fix it. You only took a bit more time to give a solution.